# Fully qualified file name in R

Tags: r, filenames

I wish to get the fully qualified name of a file in R, given any of the standard notations. For example:

- file.ext
- ~/file.ext (this case can be handled by `path.expand`)
- ../current_dir/file.ext
- *etc.*

By fully qualified file name I mean, for example, (on a Unix-like system):

> /home/user/some/path/file.ext

**(Edited - use file.path and attempt Windows support)** A crude implementation might be:

```
path.qualify <- function(path) {
  path <- path.expand(path)
  if(!grepl("^/|([A-Z|a-z]:)", path)) path <- file.path(getwd(),path)
  path
}
```

However, I'd ideally like something cross-platform that can handle relative paths with `../`, symlinks etc. An R-only solution would be preferred (rather than shell scripting or similar), but I can't find any straightforward way of doing this, short of coding it "from scratch".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you want `normalizePath()`:

```
> setwd("~/tmp/bar")
> normalizePath("../tmp.R")
[1] "/home/gavin/tmp/tmp.R"
> normalizePath("~/tmp/tmp.R")
[1] "/home/gavin/tmp/tmp.R"
> normalizePath("./foo.R")
[1] "/home/gavin/tmp/bar/foo.R"
```

For Windows, there is argument `winslash` which you might want to set all the time as it is ignored on anything other than Windows so won't affect other OSes:

```
> normalizePath("./foo.R", winslash="\\")
[1] "/home/gavin/tmp/bar/foo.R"
```

(You need to escape the `\` hence the `\\`) or

```
> normalizePath("./foo.R", winslash="/")
[1] "/home/gavin/tmp/bar/foo.R"
```

depending on how you want the path presented/used. The former is the default (`"\\"`) so you could stick with that if it suffices, without needing to set anything explicitly.

On R 2.13.0 then the `"~/file.ext"` bit also works (see comments):

```
> normalizePath("~/foo.R")
[1] "/home/gavin/foo.R"
```

Comment: Excellent, it even de-references symlinks - only problem being it doesn't seem to cover the `~/file.ext` case. Easily accounted for by using `normalizePath(path.expand(filename))`. Many thanks.

Comment: @daveslanted It does in R 2.13.0. See my updated answer. What version of R are your running?

Comment: R 2.12.2. I'll probably have to stick with the workaround for now rather than upgrade, but good to know it's been fixed in the latest stable build. Thanks again.

Comment: @daveslanted or use `file_path_as_absolute` from the standard tools package (it mucks around with `normalizePath` under the hood for you)

Comment: the winslash parameter has been added in R-2.13.  setting it to the non-default "/" allows you to split the resulting name on `.Platform$file.sep` (it is "/" also on Windows).

Answer (score 2):

I think I kind of miss the point of your question, but hopefully my answer can point you into the direction you want (it integrates your idea of using `paste` and `getwd`with `list.files`):

```
paste(getwd(),substr(list.files(full.names = TRUE), 2,1000), sep ="")
```

**Edit:** Works on windows in some tested folders.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but ideally I'm after a function which takes an arbitrary file name as an argument (such as those in the bullet list in the question) and returns the fully qualified file name.

Comment: How does this work if the user wants to pass in `"../current_dir/file.ext"` as the path to be expanded?